# Regular Expression If-Else condition example

Tags: regex

I'm trying to implement a Regular Expression 'if-else' condition.

I saw many examples stating the format as below `(?(?=regex)then|else)`.

So I gave this a try with: `(?(?=a)1|2)`.

To my understanding (what I was expecting): If there is a `1` followed by(positive look ahead) `a`, Match!. Else search for `2` and see if there is a match.

Input is as below, I was expecting 1 to get highlighted, but it turns out to be `2`.

```
1a
2a
```

Could someone please tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: Which language / tool are you using to run your regex? Lookaround conditionnals aren't supported by many.

Comment: What is your real problem? What is the real life scenario? You really can't expect any match of `abc` in a string that does not contain `abc`.

Comment: lots of help here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html

Comment: @Aaron, I am using Java. Didn't know the regex aren't supported by many. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, I want to check if a specific string1 is followed by string2(abc) in my example above, then apply some other logics. Thanks for asking

Comment: @Eric, Thanks a lot! I will go through it

Comment: You are still missing the point about the lookarounds: they are executed at the place you put them at, so, `(?(?=a)1|2)` will never attempt to match `1`, because `1` is not `a` (and `(?=a)1` means exactly that, the engine will first try to match a location immediately followed with `a` with the lookahead, and that will result in failure, so the *else* branch will trigger, `2` will be tried, not `1`. If you want to check for `a` after `1`, you'd use `(?(?=1a)1|2)`, but probably all you want is a mere alternation like  `(1(?=a)|2)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you very much! Now it is much clear. Really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(?(?=abc)1|2)` - this conditional checks, if positive lookahead was successfull.

So, first it checks, if `abc` follows current position. If that's true, match `1`. This contradicts positive lookahead, because if `abc` follows current position, you won't be able to match 1.

`2a` matches `2`, because positive lookahead fails, so engine tries to match `2`.

On the other hand, `(?(?=abc)a|2)` will match `a` in `abc`. [Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/ri5hhh/1)

Comment: Turczyn, Thank you very much for your reply. I actually just tried by changing the regex to (?(?=a)1|2), (inputs remain the same), but the '1' of '1a' still won't be detected. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: @Joe Becuase in `1a` positive lookahead `(?=a)` fails, so it don't match `1`, it tries to match `2` instead, because it's in "else" part of cinditional.

Comment: Turczyn, Thank you very much! Now I think I am much clear. Really Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From the [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html):

> A special construct `(?ifthen|else)` allows you to create conditional regular expressions. If the *if* part evaluates to `true`, then the regex engine will attempt to match the *then* part. Otherwise, the *else* part is attempted instead.

So, `(?(?=a)1|2)` regex works like this:

- If the next char to the right is `a`
- Then attempt to match and consume `1` (failure is guaranteed, since `1` != `a`)
- Else, attempt to match `2`.

What you need is a mere alternation, with a lookahead after `1` to restrict its context:

```
(1(?=a)|2)
```

It will match

- `1(?=a)` - `1` if it is followed with `a`
- `|` - or
- `2` - match `2`.

Comment: new RegExp("(?(?=a)1|2)") throws VM267:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?(?=a)1|2)/: Invalid group

Comment: @blub Of course, JavaScript regex does not support conditionals. Your pattern makes no sense, see its explanation in my answer.

Comment: "Your pattern makes no sense" That's your pattern from you answer, not mine.

Comment: @blub No, see "*What you need is a mere alternation, with a lookahead after 1 to restrict its context: `(1(?=a)|2)`* - this is my pattern and it does make sense. `(?(?=a)1|2)` has no sense (because `1` is not and cannot be `a`), and I explained it at the answer start.