# Understanding how else path in conditional regex python works

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

I tried to understand the simple regex: `([+]{1})(?(1)\d{3}|\d{2})`.

My (very probably wrong) understanding of the regex above is: If there is a single "+" then it should be followed directly by three digits, else (if there is no plus) it should look for two digits.

My two test sentences are:

```
1: "This is a +333 test." 
2: "This is a 22 test."
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/oJepMi/1/

The regex finds in 1: "+333", but does not find "22" in sentence 2:.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html mentions:

> (?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern):
>   "Will try to match with yes-pattern if the group with given id or name exists, and with no-pattern if it doesn’t."

It seems a quiet easy tasks, but I struggle to understand.

Can someone please explain how the else path concept works for python?

Best regards and many thanks
Giovanni

Comment: There is an if clause in your regex which is letting to match only 3 digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this kind of conditional does only make sense, if the group is optional or part of an alternation, thus it's actually possible to not match it.

Change your regex to `([+]{1})?(?(1)\d{3}|\d{2})` to get this to work.

Note that this will still match `22` out of `+22`. You'd have to add a negative lookahead to check for `+` it this is not intended,  e.g. `([+]{1})?(?(1)\d{3}|(?<!)\d{2})` or simplier `\+\d{3}|(?<!\+)\d{2}`

Comment: How does `'((?P<plus>[+])(?P=plus)?\d{3}|\d{2})'` work then? Do these work differently?

Comment: @RaunaqJain yes, this is a simple alternation with `\d{2}` being the second alternative.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My question was `Can someone please explain how the else path concept works for python?` I would like to understand it, not finding a workaround. Could you give me an easy understandable example sentence for the proposed regex? Thx

Comment: @giovanni In the regex you have given, the else path will never be accessed. If the capturing group is matched, it will jump into the then-path. If the capturing group isn't matched, the matching process will just stop at that point, not considering the remainder of the pattern.

Comment: @giovanni Actually, Sebastian has already provided you an example of how to use the conditional.  If that is not enough, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52495875/3832970). What is not clear? Please be very specific.

Comment: @Sebastian, I'm really sorry, I think I read the first version of the answer. Everything is clear now. Thank you guys for the explanations.